# Syntax of premake scripts

Tags: lua, premake

Can somebody explain to me what the syntax of a premake script means? A premake script is a valid lua script. Then what are `solution`, `configurations`, `project` in the below code? Variables? keywords?

```
-- A solution contains projects, and defines the available configurations
solution "MyApplication"
   configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

   -- A project defines one build target
   project "MyApplication"
      kind "ConsoleApp"
      language "C++"
      files { "**.h", "**.cpp" }

      configuration "Debug"
         defines { "DEBUG" }
         flags { "Symbols" }

      configuration "Release"
         defines { "NDEBUG" }
         flags { "Optimize" }
```

Edit: They are function calls. So Then how is this part

```
      configuration "Debug"
         defines { "DEBUG" }
         flags { "Symbols" }

      configuration "Release"
         defines { "NDEBUG" }
         flags { "Optimize" }
```

executed? the `defines` and `flags` calls are to be called according to the context of `configuartion`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Functions**

If function takes only one argument that is a table or a string the parentheses can be omitted. Refer to [3.4.10 - Function Calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10).

Additionally, in your example indention is arbitrary. You could write:

```lua
project("MyApplication")
kind("ConsoleApp")
language("C++")
files({"**.h", "**.cpp"})
```

And it would be as good as the original.

Regarding the second matter. Most likely `configuration` and related `defines` and `flags` operate on some hidden local state. When you call `configuration` it changes this local state to refer to e.g. `"Debug"` configuration and so all following calls also refer to this local state. As in:

```lua
do
   local state
   function set_state (name)
      state = name
   end
   function print_with_suffix (suffix)
      print(state, suffix)
   end
end
set_state("hello")
print_with_suffix("world") --> hello  world
```